# Permission not available in App settings

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have declared storage permission in the manifest and try to seek user permission for SDK 23 and above. But, I found an issue, I cannot see the added permission in the app settings. I have never come across such situation. Let me know where am I doing wrong. Here are the screen shots.

[image: App Settings Image]

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kinephonics">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:name=".ui.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.kinephonics.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.LandingPage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.InformationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.PlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".QuizActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.AppBaseActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.VideoPlayList"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ActivityLog"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.LockedContentActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="com.kinephonics.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.DictionaryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: share your whole manifest file as text not as image

Comment: Kindly see the edited question.

Comment: So did you ask the permission during runtime?

Comment: Yes. But Let me know one thing, wheather I ask for permission on runtime or not, all the required permissions mentioned in the manifest, must be listed in the App permissions. You can see the storage permission is not there in app permissions.

Comment: I don't know, but I don't see the point in the Android System displaying those permissions in settings if you never ask for them during runtime. Just try requesting during runtime and see if they appear.

Comment: When we mention it in Manifest, it shows up in App Settings. I am trying to request for permission at run time but, it always fail.